# Watcher not firing when contents of object changes

Tags: angularjs, last.fm

### Why is my $interval visibly refreshing the model?

I'm trying to automatically update the song that I'm playing right now and showing it on my website. For that, I used the $interval function. The problem is that the model (div) is refreshing every 10 seconds, while I want it only to refresh when the song changes (and just checking every 10 seconds)

I tried changing the $interval function with setInterval(), but no luck.

```
angular.module('lastfm-nowplaying', [])
.directive('lastfmnowplaying', ['uiCreation', 'lastFmAPI', 'lastFmParser', '$interval', function(uiCreation, lastFmAPI, lastFmParser, $interval){
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs){
      
      scope.$watch('config', function(value) {
        load();
      });

      var load = function(){
          function SongCheck(){
              var latestTrack;      
              if (scope.config){    
                  if (scope.config.apiKey){            
                      lastFmAPI.getLatestScrobbles(scope.config)
                      .then(function(data){    
                          latestTrack = lastFmParser.getLatestTrack(data);
                          angular.element(element).addClass('lastfm-nowplaying');
                          uiCreation.create(element[0], scope.config.containerClass, latestTrack);
                        }, function(reason) {
                          //Last.fm failure
                      });

                  }
                  else{
                      var latestTrack = {
                          title: scope.config.title,
                          artist: scope.config.artist,
                          largeImgUrl: scope.config.imgUrl,
                          xLargeImgUrl: scope.config.backgroundImgUrl,
                      }
                      angular.element(element).addClass('lastfm-nowplaying');
                      uiCreation.create(element[0], scope.config.containerClass, latestTrack);
                  }
              }
          }
          SongCheck();
          $interval(function () {
              SongCheck();
          }  , 8000);
      }
  };

  return {
       scope:{
            config: '=config'
       },
       link: link
  };
}])
```

The code works, but I want the model to change when a change is detected (in this case the json file).

Comment: I added the `$interval` to fix a problem. I saw other people using it in familiar codes, but in those codes the `$interval` didn't cause a real "refresh" of the content (like when refreshing a page).

Comment: Adding the $interval timer distracts from the original problem, and creates new problems. Instead of adding code that you don't understand, you should be asking about the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Watcher not firing when contents of object changes

Delete the `$interval` timer and use the "deep watch" version of the watcher:

```
  scope.$watch('config', function(value) {
    load(value);
  ̶}̶)̶;̶
  }, true);
```

Normally the watcher only fires when the object *reference* changes. Set the second argument to `true` to have the watcher fire when the object *contents* changes.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! You set me in the right direction.
It looks like that the config is only showing the API and username, but not the Json file.
I edited the config so I can read the content of the JSON in the console. Any idea how I can read the json through the `('config', function(value...` code? I'll update the code as a reply.

Comment: I'll mark it as solved, though it didn't work for me yet. The problem I'm facing now is somewhat different, but still related to this one.

Comment: How to get data from a server is a whole new question.

Comment: I made a new post. I tried to describe the problem as best as I can. Maybe you can help out? I'm stuck